# Attempting to automate file transfer from cisco switch to file server

Tags: linux, bash, tcl, cisco, cisco-ios

I am attempted to automate a weekly file backup of my switch/router configurations to a file server while making changes to the file name before it sends. I work in a secure facility on an isolated network so the software I can use is limited. I am automating this using tcl as I am running the automation on the switches/routers. Currently the only issue that I am running into are the character returns. Currently my script looks like this:

```
set source_file "sourcefile.txt"
set date [clock format [clock seconds] -format "%Y%m%d"]
set destination_file "$source_file-$date"
set username "username"
set password "password"
copy run $source_file
copy $source_file $destination_file
delete /force $source_file
copy $destination_file scp://$username:$password@x.x.x.x//path/to/fileshare/$destination_file
delete /force $destination_file
```

I know there is probably a better way to do this but I am new to this so this is what I got. I save the running configuration to the flash, rename this file with todays date, delete the original file (to not take up room on the flash), send the file with the date over scp to the fileshare, and delete said file from flash. My issue is that I am forced to press "enter" on saving a file to flash. Is there any way around this? So far I have not been able to find a way around this as anything I type in (\r or \r\n) with be used as the filename.

Comment: How is your script being triggered to run? By you connecting from outside, by cron, or what?

Comment: Cron. It is set to run once a week.

Comment: Solutions should be added with the "Post Your Answer" button, never by editing the question. Doing so lets your question and your answer be voted on separately (so you can get points for each independently), and lets you mark the question as solved by clicking the checkbox next to your answer (after a delay to allow others to propose their own answers has passed).

Comment: While I added your answer as a new "Community Wiki" answer on the question (CW making so I don't receive any points for it), if you want to add a version that's credited to your name, let me know and I'll vote to delete the CW one.

Comment: first time using stack overflow so thanks for the tips. I didn't realize that I could answer my own question. I don't care about the credit so it's fine to keep it this way.

Comment: Good deal. BTW, if you consider the question adequately solved that it doesn't need more answers, clicking the checkbox next to an answer will mark that answer as "accepted", and change the color scheme &c that the question has in search results to show that it has an acceptable answer attached.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>*[The below was written by Kenchiken, originally added as a self-answer edited into the question.](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77700205/3)*</sub>

---

What I did was archive the running configuration and set the path for my file server and set the trigger to "write memory". The archive command automatically appends a date/time to the file. I then set up a kron session to run once a week which will run the "write memory" command and trigger the archive.

```
archive 
path path/to/file/server
write-memory

kron policy-list backupconfig
cli write memory

kron occurrence backupconfig at 02:00 mon recurring
kron policy-list backupconfig
```